# XPages how to call function for each document in a repeat

Tags: xpages-ssjs

In my XPage I have a repeat control. For each document in that repeat control I need to pass into a function which performs some crazy logic and potentially updates that document.

The only way I can think of is to have a hidden computed text with logic that call the function. Is there a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to use the currentDocument in the beforePageLoad event to call a function which then gets a collection of document instead of using the repeat control document.